Using Git commands with Service Principal authentication
I have been granted service principal access to my Azure DevOps repository. Below is the script I'm using:
PowerShell
$resource="499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798"
$TenantId=" "
$ClientId=" "
$ClientSecret=" "
$TokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantID/oauth2/token/" 

$Body = "client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&resource=$Resource&grant_type=client_credentials"
$TokenResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TokenUri -Body $Body -Method "POST"
$AccesToken = $TokenResult.access_token

$URI= "https://$AccesToken@dev.azure.com/Org/Project/_git/Repo"

git clone $URI "C:\Users\DBT\Desktop\git" 
cd "C:\Users\DBT\Desktop\git" (Get-Item .).FullName 
$gitCmd = "git -c http.extraheader='AUTHORIZATION: bearer $AccesToken'" 
Invoke-Expression "$gitCmd add ." 
Invoke-Expression "$gitCmd commit -m 'Commit message'" 
Invoke-Expression "$gitCmd push"

I'm able to successfully clone the repository, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to commit and push changes. The error message I'm receiving is: git: Author identity unknown.
How can I use service principal authentication to commit and push changes to Azure DevOps/Git?

Hi Ahwan, Git requires that a username and email be set for commits because it uses this information to track who has made changes to the repository and record them in history. So please add git config --global user.name "ServicePrincipal" and git config --global user.email "serviceprincipal@domain.com" to your script before trying to commit and push changes.

According to the error git: Author identity unknown, it seems that you didn't set your account's default identity before trying to commit and push changes. Git requires that a username and email be set for commits because it uses this information to track who has made changes to the repository and record them in history.
You can check your global Git configuration for username and email by running the following commands:
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email

These commands will output the current global user name and email configured for Git. If they are not set, you will see no output.
Please set your account's default identity with the following commands before the commit and push commands:
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your.email@example.com"

As the service principal has no associated email or user identity, you can set an arbitrary username and email, and it does not need to be tied to an actual user. For example:
git config --global user.name "ServicePrincipal"
git config --global user.email "serviceprincipal@domain.com"


can you please confirm whether this is doable at service principal level? As Service principal doesn't have any email aspect. So then does it mean we cannot use app  for git commands except clone

Hi @Nandan, you are correct that a service principal has no associated email or user identity. However, Git requires that a username and email be set for commits because it uses this information to track who has made changes to the repository and record them in history. You can satisfy Git’s requirements by setting an arbitrary username and email and continue to commit and push changes, even when using a service principal. This does not need to be tied to an actual user. I added an example in the answer.
